# Getting the position of cursor in textarea tag

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

So I am working on a React Project and I want one functionality to be like when a user is writing in a Textarea, he will get suggestions in the form of a popover list. And the position of the popover will be the position of the cursor.

For the popover, i am using Material UI Popover.

```
<Popover
   id={id}
   open={open}
   anchorEl={anchorEl}
   onClose={handleClose}
   anchorOrigin={{
     vertical: 'bottom',
     horizontal: 'center',
   }}
   transformOrigin={{
     vertical: 'top',
     horizontal: 'center',
   }}
 >
   { List of Suggestions Here }

 </Popover>
```

But now I need to have the anchorEl set to the position of the cursor of Textarea.
Anyone has any ideas ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#context-menu) has an example for how to do this with the Menu component, which uses Popover under the hood and has the same "anchorPosition" prop.

This is copied straight from the documentation and I'm sure will transfer to the Popover component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const initialState = {
  mouseX: null,
  mouseY: null,
};

export default function ContextMenu() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<{
    mouseX: null | number;
    mouseY: null | number;
  }>(initialState);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState({
      mouseX: event.clientX - 2,
      mouseY: event.clientY - 4,
    });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setState(initialState);
  };

  return (
    <div onContextMenu={handleClick} style={{ cursor: 'context-menu' }}>
      <Typography>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ipsum purus, bibendum sit
        amet vulputate eget, porta semper ligula. Donec bibendum vulputate erat, ac fringilla mi
        finibus nec. Donec ac dolor sed dolor porttitor blandit vel vel purus. Fusce vel malesuada
        ligula. Nam quis vehicula ante, eu finibus est. Proin ullamcorper fermentum orci, quis
        finibus massa. Nunc lobortis, massa ut rutrum ultrices, metus metus finibus ex, sit amet
        facilisis neque enim sed neque. Quisque accumsan metus vel maximus consequat. Suspendisse
        lacinia tellus a libero volutpat maximus.
      </Typography>
      <Menu
        keepMounted
        open={state.mouseY !== null}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorReference="anchorPosition"
        anchorPosition={
          state.mouseY !== null && state.mouseX !== null
            ? { top: state.mouseY, left: state.mouseX }
            : undefined
        }
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Copy</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Print</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Highlight</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Email</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```